# Undefined variable in Blade template used in a Notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification

I have a message.blade in which I'm trying to access a variable set in my Notification class:

```
{{ $testVar }}
```

Class `SimpleMessage` has a `toArray` method that looks like this:

```
public function toArray()
{
    return [
        'level' => $this->level,
        'subject' => $this->subject,
        'greeting' => $this->greeting,
        'salutation' => $this->salutation,
        'introLines' => $this->introLines,
        'outroLines' => $this->outroLines,
        'actionText' => $this->actionText,
        'actionUrl' => $this->actionUrl,
        'testVar' => 'test'
    ];
}
```

I'm using `MailMessage` as a child class of `SimpleMessage`, in which I have this method:

```
/**
 * Get the data array for the mail message.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function data()
{
    return array_merge($this->toArray(), $this->viewData);
}
```

There is no `toArray()` method in `MailMessage`, so that points to the superclass `SimpleMessage`.

However, I get this error:

```
"message": "Undefined variable: testVar (View: ...\\message.blade.php)
```

How do I correctly pass this variable to my view?

**EDIT**
My implementation class looks like this:

```
class NewCommentNotification extends Notification
{
    /**
     * @var Examination
     */
    private $examination;

    public $testVar = 'bladiebla';

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param Examination $examination
     */
    public function __construct(Examination $examination)
    {
        $this->examination  = $examination;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('message')
            ->subject('subject')
            ->action('action', 'url');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->examination->id,
            'title' => 'title',
            'uri' => 'edit',
            'message' => 'message',
            'action' => 'newExaminationCommentMessage',
            'testVar' => $this->testVar
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation on this matter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data)?

Comment: can you post your full `class` here

Comment: @Namoshek yeah, but that's using Mail and I'm using Notification. I don't think those methods apply.

Comment: @KaranSadana which one?

Comment: from where you sending variable to blade. like `MailMessage ` i guss

Comment: @Sherlock and have your tried setting `public $testVar` in your class, and does it still throw the same exception?

Comment: @nakov yeah, same message.

Comment: @KaranSadana I added some more code.

Comment: Only way I see right now is setting `$mailMessage->viewData = ['testVar' => 'foo'];` directly. It is public. Not very nice though...

Comment: @Namoshek that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try to rename method "toArray", in laravel exist the same method. Change name method and try again